# "Chinese Postman" online-calc

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, grass-gis

Before I reinvent the wheel for a 1-time calculation....
Does there exist an online Calculator, which'll accept point upload (250-1000) and in return provide me (maybe based on OSM data) with a route or CP-sorted point listing ?

Comment: There used to be one, but the site went dark a while back. Most of the existing online tools limit you to a small number of points, and won't be practical for your situation. There are a number of standalone utilities and GIS algorithms that will handle this nicely; is there a reason it needs to be online?